# How to install Nginx in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, nginx

Recently I have installed a LAMP server in my Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS.

Now how can I install Nginx and implement with my present LAMP Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Nginx in your Ubuntu , open your terminal and type as

```
sudo -i
add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/development
apt-get update 
apt-get install nginx
```

that will install nginx in your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

From [Nginx Wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Install):

Open a terminal and enter the commands (remember to replace the values!):

```
sudo -s
nginx=stable # use nginx=development for latest development version
ubuntu=trusty # Replace this with your ubuntu version!
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/$nginx/ubuntu $ubuntu main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-$nginx-$ubuntu.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C300EE8C
apt-get update 
apt-get install nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Login as Root User and type command:

Command: (apt-get update && apt-get install nginx;)

This command will install default version of nginx that comes with ubuntu software repository with latest updates.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU. Please edit our question in order to eliminate the need to login as root.  Use `sudo` instead. You may also consider to add for which version of Ubuntu your answer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Install nginx on ubuntu with easy steps

Update package with latest version

```
sudo apt update
```

Install nginx

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

Verify nginx version

```
nginx -V
```

Answer (score -1):

To install [stable Nginx](https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/ubuntu/stable) Open terminal and run the following commands:::

```
sudo su
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```